# How to write to the standard input of a Windows process?

Tags: c, windows, process, stdin

I run another executable as a child process with `CreateProcess()`. On Linux, I can just `read()` from a file and `write()` to the standard input of the process (or use `sendfile()`.) How can I do that on Windows?

Comment: You have to redirect the STDIN of the new process you are creating, then you can write to it. MSDN has an example of exactly that: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. Is there a way to use `write()` with the pipe so that I don't have to rewrite larger parts of the code am trying to port?

Comment: Use [`_open_osfhandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts1c9x.aspx) to associate a Win32 `HANDLE` with a C-style file descriptor.  Otherwise, stop using `write()` on Windows and use `WriteFile()` instead.